# A spirit, or maybe a language

Tags: riddle

> My first name is a spirit, or maybe a language, or maybe my middle name.
>
> My middle name is a sound, or maybe a command, or maybe my last name.
>
> My surname is eleven, or maybe a direction, or maybe my first name.

Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a somewhat spoileriffic warning for anyone trying to solve this on their own: This is pretty much unsolvable unless

> you have at least a rudimentary understanding of East Asian languages and culture.

The cyclic thing with the first name maybe being the second, etc, comes from

> the way westerners often insist on writing the given name(s) before the family name, even though the family name is always written first in Chinese

With all this out of the way, here are the rest of the clues:

Eleven or direction

> Xi, 11 in roman numerals, "west" in Chinese (written and pronounced differently though)

Spirit or language

> Jin (djinn or [Jin Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_Chinese))

Sound or command

> Ping (onomatopoetic word, or the command to check network connectivity between two computers)

Which gives the final answer of

> [Xi Jinping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_Jinping), the guy that ruined the perfect gag of ["Who is the leader of China?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hu_Jintao)

Comment: nice one, definitely wouldn't have gotten it myself.